# Getting ORACLE_HOME must be set and %ORACLE_HOME%\database must be writeable createdb terminated unsucessfully while creating db in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I am getting the following error and the process of creating a DB gets terminated automatically while creating a DB in PostgreSQL.

> ORACLE_HOME must be set and %ORACLE_HOME%\database must be writeable
>   createdb terminated unsucessfully.

[image]

How to create a Database in Postgres using `createdb` command?

Running the same command on the Git Bash also doesn't work, the process doesn't getting terminated and it showing as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Postgres does not need an `ORACLE_HOME`. what does `where createdb` show you? Can you connect using a sql client (e.g. `psql`) and then run the **SQL** command `create database ..;`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Yeah it's doesn't need `ORABLE_HOME` that's why I am also confused. `createdb` is a command - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-createdb.html I have used `create database` command also it's not working. Click this link to view the error of `create database` - https://i.postimg.cc/wv5npLkB/Capture.png

Comment: You need to **first** start `psql`, connect to the server in which you want to create the database, **then** run the SQL command. You are prompted for connection information in that screen. Just start `psql -U postgres postgres` from the regular command line.

Comment: Again: what does `where createdb` show you in the command line?

Comment: My server is already running.

Comment: If Postgres is running then start `cmd.exe`, type `psq -U postgres postgres` enter the password **then** once you get the `psql` prompt, run the SQL commands

Comment: `where createdb` shows `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\CreateDB.bat`
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe`

Comment: Then run `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe"` instead of just `createdb` on the command line. Or use `psql`

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name You message -  If Postgres is running then start cmd.exe, type psq -U postgres postgres enter the password then once you get the psql prompt, run the SQL commands worked for me....

Comment: I used `create database example;` and this worked for me

Comment: But then how to run `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe"` instead of just createdb?

Comment: You type `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe"` at the command line

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's showing this - `createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin"`
It asked for for password twice, I am 100% sure that it's correct one, but still it says authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave this as a comment but I cannot, there are several issues that may be happening here, the first that comes to mind is that your command prompt is not showing as admin. This can also be a path issue, because sometimes cmd will not recognize paths for software except when you try to use it on the folder its installed. Another common issue with Windows is that sometimes you want to run the GUI software instead of cmd, and if you absolutely need cmd try powershell with admin rights. 
The error it gives makes me believe that its either a path error or a user rights error, I also agree with the comments. My suggestion if you keep having issues like this who are either depending on your windows path system or your system requirements in general is to try using Anaconda or (conda), this will give you a clean environment to properly see what you did wrong.